# What is the most agreed upon quantum mechanical equation of motion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

On multiple Wikipedia articles, it mentions several quantum mechanical equations of motion, namely those by [Schrödinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture) and [Heisenberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture). Which one is the most accurate and agreed upon quantum mechanical equation of motion?

Comment: Don't forget the Dirac picture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Schrödinger picture and the Heisenberg picture are unitarily equivalent. None is more accurate, more fundamental, or in any other objective sense "better" than the other.

Comment: @DamonBlevins please note that on this site if the asker's question is solved by an answer, the answer should be accepted. For details see [StackExchange tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

They are referring to the Schrodinger and Heisenberg "pictures." In the Schrodinger picture states change over time and operators remain constant over time. In the Heisenberg picture operators change over time, and states do not change. Both pictures give the same numerical answers to any given problem, because they are unitarily equivalent.